# Button command class to take a parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, command

Using c# + wpf + mvvm I am trying to make a more or less generic "buttoncommand" class following level 4 at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level

I have a datagrid thats bound to `observablecollection<mySpecialClass>` and a button bound a command that adds row and takes no parameters that works fine. 
However  I would like to have buttons to insert and remove rows in the grid, that would take the index of the row that is currently active/selected.

I have tried to change the buttoncommand to the following (changing `Action what` to `Action<object> what`):

```
public class ButtonCommandi : ICommand
  {
    private Action<object> _whattoExecute;
    private Func<bool> _whentoExecute;
    public ButtonCommandi(Action<object> what, Func<bool> when)
    {
      _whattoExecute = what;
      _whentoExecute = when;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return _whentoExecute(); 
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      _whattoExecute(parameter); 
    }
  }
}
```

However, in my viewmodel, as I try to create instances of the class in the constructor:

```
public class MyViewModelClass
{
  private ButtonCommand _objAppendTerrainPointCommand;
  private ButtonCommandi _objInsertTerrainPointCommand;
  private MyModelClass _mymodel;  
  public MyVeiwModelClass()
    {
      ...
      _objAppendRowCommand = new ButtonCommand(_mymodel.Append, _mymodel.IsPossibleToAppend);
      _objInsertRowCommand= new ButtonCommandi(
        delegate(object i) { _mymodel.InsertRow(i); }, _mymodel.IsPossibleToInsert);
      ...
    }
```

it says that "the best overloaded method match for 'MyModelClass.InsertRow(int)' has some invalid arguments". I have tried some different versions of the `new ButtonCommandi(..)` but cannot seem to find the way.

in MyModelClass the function looks like this:

```
internal void InsertRow(int idx)
    {
        _myObsColSpecial.Insert(idx);
    }
```

Does anyone have a good hint how to have this work? (I am new to the wpf, mvvm and c# so bear with me. As far as I understand there seems to be a lot of ways to accomplish something like this but since I started down this way, it would be nice not to have to rewrite a "ton" of code :) )

Comment: _mymodel.InsertRow((int)i);

Answer (score 0):

For RelayCommand that passes an object try this....

```
class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In your View Model...

```
class MainWindowVM
{
    public RelayCommand<string> WindowCommand { get; set; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
          WindowCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnWindowCommand);
    }

    private void OnWindowCommand(string obj)
    {
        // obj is the string passed from the Button CommandParameter
    }
}
```

In your XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowVM/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding WindowCommand}" CommandParameter="Test" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works nicely with one parameter. It says in the comments that it works with functions taking no parameter (null) but this I don't seem to get to work.. could you elaborate a bit? Or do I have to creat e a separate RelayCommand class for this without the `<T>` ??